# Django Model Error for __unicode__ method

Tags: python, django

I have the following python code in a Django project:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __unicode__(self)
    return self.choice_text
```

When I run the python manage.py validate command I get the following error:

```
 def __unicode__(self)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `:`

Change

```
def __unicode__(self)
```

to

```
def __unicode__(self):
```

Also, notice the indentation.

```
def __unicode__(self): 
    return u'{0}'.format(self.choice_text)
    #^ Indentation
```

Comment: Got it! I will accept answer in 10 minutes. As soon as I can accept! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You forget the identation and the ":"
It should be :

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```